# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE when using bash script with npm

Tags: node.js, bash

I am simply trying to use some bash to check some things then run the commands I want. But I'm getting stuck at the first hurdle:

**hutber.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hutber' ; exit 1;
```

**package.json**

```
"hutber": "./hutber.sh"
```

**terminal**

```
hutber@hutber-mint /var/www/mvt-framework $ npm run hutber

> mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber /var/www/mvt-framework
> ./hutber.sh

hutber
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber: `./hutber.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hutber/.npm/_logs/2017-12-05T15_52_44_355Z-debug.log
```

**error log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'hutber' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prehutber', 'hutber', 'posthutber' ]
5 info lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~prehutber: mvt-framework@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: mvt-framework@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: PATH: /home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/mvt-framework/node_modules/.bin:/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin:/home/hutber/bin:/home/hutber/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hutber/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/hutber/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
9 verbose lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: CWD: /var/www/mvt-framework
10 silly lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: Args: [ '-c', './hutber.sh' ]
11 silly lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mvt-framework@0.0.1~hutber: Failed to exec hutber script
13 verbose stack Error: mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber: `./hutber.sh`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid mvt-framework@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /var/www/mvt-framework
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-53-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/node" "/home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/npm" "run" "hutber"
18 verbose node v8.7.0
19 verbose npm  v5.4.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber: `./hutber.sh`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mvt-framework@0.0.1 hutber script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: How about posting /home/hutber/.npm/_logs/2017-12-05T15_52_44_355Z-debug.log?

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can you post hutber.sh please

Comment: Its already there at the top of the question :)

Comment: Whoops! Sorry! I missed that..not sure what else to add. not much looking wrong to me..

Comment: I imagine it must be the way npm executes the file or similar.

Answer (score 3):

It works as expected.
You end your bash script with a code error 1, used for catching general errors, so *npm* throws an error.

> error code ELIFECYCLE
>   error errno 1

It would end without error, if you change for a code 0:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hutber' ; exit 0;
```